# Sparkr write DF as file csv/txt

Tags: r, apache-spark, sparkr

Hi I'm working on sparkR in yarn mode.

I need to write a sparkr df to a csv/txt file.

I saw that there is `write.df` but it writes parquet files.

I tried to do this things

```
RdataFrame<-collect(SparkRDF)
write.table(RdataFrame, ..)
```

But I got many WARN and some ERROR on contextCleaner.

Is there any way ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**Spark 2.0+**

You can use `write.text` function:

> Save the content of the SparkDataFrame in a text file at the
>        specified path. The SparkDataFrame must have only one column of
>        string type with the name "value". Each row becomes a new line in
>        the output file.

```
write.text(df, path)
```

or `write.df` with built-in SparkR `csv` writer:

```
write.df(df, path, source="csv")
```

**Spark 1.x**

You can use [`spark-csv`](https://github.com/databricks/spark-csv) package:

```
write.df(SparkRDF, "foo.csv", "com.databricks.spark.csv", ...)
```

It can be added for example with `packages` argument to `SparkR` / `spark-submit`:

```
sparkR --packages com.databricks:spark-csv_2.10:1.3.0 # For Scala 2.10
sparkR --packages com.databricks:spark-csv_2.11:1.3.0 # For Scala 2.11
```

For other options see [the official documentation](https://github.com/databricks/spark-csv#r-api)

Comment: Hey zero , there is a way to write it as one file and not part-xxx?
I tried to do `repartition(A,1)` and then `write.df` but it don't works.

Comment: `repartition(..., 1)` should work but really don't use it. If output is small enough just collect and write locally. If not you're passing everything at least twice through a single machine.

Comment: well output is like 2~3GB * 30 file and they would become too many files as part-xxx.
Ill try with collect and `write.table` in R, hope it will not take so much.
Thanks.

Comment: Is it normal that we lose columns names when writing with write.df ?